# Geopackage drops fields during import

Tags: ogr2ogr, geopackage, missing-data

When I use the ogr2ogr -f command to create a geopackage the first layer imports correctly but every layer after that drops fields. Can anybody explain why it does this?

Comment: What are you converting from? Shapefiles? What's your command lines?